# Placed a Table View inside a scroll view, now I can't use the swipe to delete

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I placed a `TableView` inside a `ScrollView` with multiple `Views`. The point of this is so that when the user scrolls right, the next `view` will appear with a different `table`. This is working, however, I now can't delete items inside the table because when I swipe right it will only lead me to the next view. Is there any way to resolve this? I already implemented the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` function.
Thanks!

Comment: post your layout/java class file so we can see whats going on.

Comment: Java class file? Wrong platform, buddy.

Answer (score 0):

`UIScrollView` has a method called 
`touchesShouldCancel(in view: UIView) -> Bool`

The method cancels touch events that are inside the scroll view's content view.

Since table views are subclasses of `UIView` you can pass it in there.

This should prevent any of the scroll view touch events and allow you to interact with the table view like before.

Edit: 
Assuming you're using storyboards, create an outlet from your storyboard to your view controller

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

Then you can add `tableView` to the method in your `viewDidLoad`

```
scrollView.touchesShouldCancel(in: tableView)
```

From the docs:

`The default returned value is true if view is not a UIControl object; otherwise, it returns false.`

Comment: I implemented the method like this ` func touchesShouldCancel(in view:UITableView) -> Bool{
        return true
    }´ but it still doesn't work. How should I implement it?

Comment: Make sure you have an instance of the table view that you're using. If you are using storyboards you can create an outlet of your tableView to your controller. 
Calling `UITableView` won't work.

Comment: yep, I did have an outlet of my tableView. Still doesn't work. Do I need any specific subclass to use `touchesShouldCancel(in view: UIView) -> Bool?`

Comment: You need to use it from the scrollView, so I assume you have an outlet for your scrollView as well. Check my edit again

Comment: `func scrollView.touchesShouldCancel(in: tableView)` so it should look like this? if so, it's displaying a bunch of errors

Comment: No... You would not need the `func` you're calling the scrollView's method in `viewDidLoad` to set everything up

Comment: `override func viewDidLoad() {`
        `super.viewDidLoad()`
       `self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()`
        `scrollView.touchesShouldCancel(in view: tableView) -> Bool {`
           `return true`
       ` }`   this is what I'm doing

Comment: you just need `scrollView.touchesShouldCancel(in view: tableView)`... you don't need the `-> Bool { return true } part

Comment: Aren't you just calling this function and getting a bool back? And isn't the function just checking if the view is a UIControl? Correct me if I'm wrong but you might as well just type true in viewDidLoad